# Rating based off play level?

Tags: software, rating

Is there a program that can tell your rating based off *how well* you play in the game? (NOT based on result). Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called [Intrinsic Performance Rating](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/papers/pdf/Reg12IPRs.pdf).

There has been a [Kaggle Competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/finding-elo/forums/t/13008/congrats-to-the-winner) in which the winner predicted the Elo on the basis of a single game with an average error of 150 points.

As far as I know there is no single piece of software that gives you these predictions, but the Kaggle Competition provides links to the code used by the participants.

Comment: +1 brilliant. I didn't know there was such a competition. Thanks for sharing!